# Laravel 5 deployment to heroku: Error output: PHP Fatal error: Class not found in ProviderRepository.php

Tags: php, laravel, heroku, web-deployment, laravel-5

Beware: Beginner here.

I have successfully deployed a barebones copy of a laravel 5 project to heroku.

But when I try to deploy now after having added some files + some composer packages(namely [laravel-debugbar](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar/tree/2.0)), I get this error when I do
`$ git push heroku master`

```
remote: Error Output: PHP Fatal error: Class 'Barryvdh\debugbar\ServiceProvider'not found in /tmp/build_855da4ace28f1a4e714d4ebf8b1dd1d4/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/foundation/ProviderRepository.php on line 150
```

I am not sure if it helps, but I use Windows 8.1 with Homestead. The code works just fine in development.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Heroku does automatically install dependencies by running `composer update` when you push. However it does that without installing `require-dev` dependencies. (using the `--no-dev` flag)

The quickest solution is to just define the dependencies you need on heroku in the `require` section.

(It might be possible to change that behavior of heroku, but I don't know how)

Comment: No you have to run `composer update` on the server itself. It will download the dependencies into the `vendor` directory, which is not included in your git repository (that's why pushing doesn't help)

Comment: Hmm apparently heroku should update composer dependencies on its own. Do you have the `composer.json` checked in?

Comment: Is it possible that you have added it under `require-dev`?

Comment: BOOM! Moved "barryvdh/laravel-debugbar": "1.*" from require-dev to require, ran composer update, pushed to git + heroku, and now everything runs full steam ahead. Thank you so much!